# Fading UILabel in from left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I want to animate a UILabel to fade text in from left to right. My code below fades the entire UILabel in at once, but I would like to go letter by letter or word by word. Also, words can be added to this text, and when that happens I only want to fade in the new words, not the entire UILabel again.

```
__weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
weakSelf.label.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{ weakSelf.label.alpha = 1;}
                 completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I know how I would do it. I would make a mask containing a gradient, and animate the mask across the front of the label.

Here's the result when I do that (don't know whether it's exactly what you have in mind, but perhaps it's a start):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code to achieve this effect, please?

Answer (score 4):

I have done this once before with decent results. You will probably have to tweak it to your preference.

First step is to create a gradient image to match the way you want the text to fade in. If your text color is black you can try this.

```
- (UIImage *)labelTextGradientImage
{
    CAGradientLayer *l = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    l.frame = self.label.bounds;
    l.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];
    l.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0f);
    l.startPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.0f);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.label.frame.size);
    [l renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *textGradientImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return textGradientImage;
}
```

That code creates an black image that should fade from left to right.

Next, when you create you label, you need to set its text color based from a pattern made from the image we just generated.

```
self.label.alpha = 0;
self.label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self labelTextGradientImage]];
```

Assuming that works, the last step is to animate the label into view and change its text color while that happens.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.label duration:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.label.alpha = 1;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

The animation code is a little funky because the UILabel's textColor property doesn't seem to be animatable with a UIViewAnimation.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve this and created a function within a UIView extension:

```
@discardableResult public func addSlidingGradientLayer(withDuration duration: Double = 3.0, animationDelegate delegate: CAAnimationDelegate? = nil) -> CAGradientLayer {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: -1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

    let gradientAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "startPoint")
    gradientAnimation.fromValue = gradientLayer.startPoint
    gradientAnimation.toValue = gradientLayer.endPoint
    gradientAnimation.duration = duration
    gradientAnimation.delegate = delegate

    gradientLayer.add(gradientAnimation, forKey: "startPoint")

    layer.mask = gradientLayer

    return gradientLayer

}
```

To begin with we create a `CAGradientLayer` instance that we use as a mask for a view (in this case a `UILabel`).

We then create a `CABasicAnimation` instance, which we use to animate the `startPoint` of the `CAGradientLayer`. This has the effect of sliding the `startPoint` from left to right with some supplied `duration` value.

Finally, we an also the delegate of the `CABasicAnimation`. Then, if we adhere to the `CAAnimationDelegate` protocol, we can execute some code after the animation completes.

This is how you might use this extension:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!

    private func configureSomeLabel() {
        someLabel.text = "Sliding into existence!"
        someLabel.sizeToFit()
        someLabel.addSlidingGradientLayer(withDuration: 3.0, animationDelegate: self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureSomeLabel()
    }

}
```

Where `someLabel` has been hooked up to your storyboard. And as we've assigned this view controller as the animation delegate we need to add:

```
extension ViewController: CAAnimationDelegate {
    func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        someLabel.layer.mask = nil
    }
}
```

where I have chosen to remove the masking layer.

Hope this helps someone!